# Embedding PDF in HTML when the file is outside the application folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, stream, google-docs

I am saving PDF files in a folder in the server outside the web application (for security reasons) and I need to preview the files using google docs.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=????&embedded=true" 
        style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Until now, I made them available for download by Redirecting in a form with the filepath as an argument:

```
string path = Request.QueryString["src"];
int index = Request.QueryString["src"].ToString().LastIndexOf("\\");
string filename = Request.QueryString["src"].ToString().Substring(index + 1);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[fileSize];
fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, fileSize);
fileStream.Close();
Response.ContentType = ContType(path);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename);
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
Response.End();
```

I tried adding the url `file.aspx?src=C:\...` as the argument of the url of the google doc iframe, say

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?url=file.aspx?src=C:\...
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any other way I can assign a URL to a stream?

Comment: Unsure you (still) need the additional header `content-disposition` if Google docs is the "client" (you're no longer forcing the client to download a file). Hth...

Comment: the problem is that i cannot write a url with parameters as a parameter of docs.google.com. it's like nested query strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url='file.aspx?src='C:\storage\test.pdf''&embedded=true" 
        style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Alternating ' with " as needed.

As a side note, I would advise you against sending full file paths from the server to a client's browser. That sounds like putting a draft of the location inside your house of your 50" TV, Blue-ray player, computer and other valuables in your front door, for any potential thief to contemplate.

As an alternative, you can use a database or an XML file with IDs to identify each file, and read the file path from there instead.